# Laravel Redis / How to you flush only a specific redis database?

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, laravel-6

As you know Redis could have several databases, in my laravel setup ive defined 3 of them and using 2 at least

```
'0' (default)
'1' (cache)
'2' (queue)
```

Thats what ive set in **config/database.php**

Furthermore, due to certain need I clear all cache using `flushall()`  method:

```
@Cache::flush();
@Redis::flushall();
```

However, it also clears the queue jobs which is not what I want. So is there a way to only flush database 0 and database 1 and not database 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [select](https://redis.io/commands/select) and [flushdb](https://redis.io/commands/flushdb) commands together to flush only selected database.

> Select the Redis logical database having the specified zero-based numeric index. New connections always use the database 0.

> Delete all the keys of the currently selected DB.

The following will select the database `1` first and flush only `1`.

```
Redis::select(1);
Redis::flushdb();
```

It is going to execute following commands in redis;

```
1596794331.068032 [0 127.0.0.1:55088] "SELECT" "1"
1596794331.071332 [1 127.0.0.1:55088] "FLUSHDB"
```

Comment: @RaheelHasan just documentation :) -- hope it works on your case.

Comment: What about `Cache::flush()`? in some places im using `Cache` facade instead of Redis facade as I could use for example `rememberForever` which in the documentation is a method of Cache class.

Comment: @RaheelHasan yes it works too. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php#L217 it also invokes the same redis method behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

`redis-cli -n [database number] flushdb`